# How do i configure multiple cores on embedded solr with raw spring-data-solr

Tags: spring, configuration, multicore, spring-data-solr

I would like to add another core to my Solr 5.5.0 embedded server environment.
"In my world" i create an embedded server and let spring-data load the core configurations. But with my solution it seems that all data go into the default core "collection1". So far i couldn't find an example beside spring-boot. But that is not an option.

My configuration looks like this so far:

```
@Import({
    AppctxSolrEmbedded.class,
    AppctxSolrHttp.class
})
@EnableSolrRepositories(value = "de.my.application.*.repository", multicoreSupport = true)
@Configuration
public class AppctxSolr {

    public @Bean SolrTemplate solrTemplate(
            @Named("solrClient") SolrClient solrClient) {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient, "collection1");
    }

    public @Bean SolrTemplate operatorSolrTemplate(
            @Named("solrClient") SolrClient solrClient) {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrClient, "operator1");
    }
}

@Dev @Qual @RemoteDev
@Configuration
public class AppctxSolrEmbedded {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean solrClient(
            @Value("${solr.server}") String solrHome) {
        EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean factory = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean();
        factory.setSolrHome(solrHome);
        return factory;
    }
}

@Prod
@Configuration
public class AppctxSolrHttp {

    @Bean
    public HttpSolrClientFactoryBean solrClient(
            @Value("${solr.server}") String baseURL) {
        HttpSolrClientFactoryBean factory = new HttpSolrClientFactoryBean();
        factory.setUrl(baseURL);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(multicoreSupport = true)
public class MulticoreSolrConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private SolrClient solrClient;

  @Bean
  public SolrOperations solrTemplate() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    return new SolrTemplate(this.solrClient);
  }

  @Bean
  public MulticoreSolrClientFactory multicoreSolrClientFactory()
      throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    return new MulticoreSolrClientFactory(this.solrClient, "operator1", "collection1");
  }

  @Bean(name = "operatorSolrClient")
  public SolrClient operatorSolrClient() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    return this.multicoreSolrClientFactory().getSolrClient("operator1");
  }

  @Bean(name = "operatorSolrTemplate")
  public SolrTemplate operatorSolrTemplate() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    return new SolrTemplate(this.operatorSolrClient());
  }
}

  @Bean(name = "collectionSolrClient")
  public SolrClient collectionSolrClient() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    return this.multicoreSolrClientFactory().getSolrClient("collection1");
  }

  @Bean(name = "collectionSolrTemplate")
  public SolrTemplate collectionSolrTemplate() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    return new SolrTemplate(this.collectionSolrClient());
  }
}
```

And then instead of AppctxSolrEmbedded and AppctxSolrHttp, you can do something like this

```
@Configuration
class SolrConfiguration {

  private final SolrProperties solrProperties; // Has details about solr host, port, directory .....

  @Autowired
  public SolrConfiguration(final SolrProperties solrProperties) {
    this.solrProperties = solrProperties;
  }

  @Bean
  SolrClient solrClient() {
    final SolrClient solrClient;
    if (this.solrProperties.isEmbedded()) {
      solrClient = createEmbeddedSolrClient();
    } else {
      solrClient = createStandaloneSolrClient();
    }

    return solrClient;
  }

  private SolrClient createEmbeddedSolrClient() {
    final String solrConfigurationFolder = this.solrProperties.getSolr().getHome();

    final EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setSolrHome(solrConfigurationFolder);

    return factoryBean.getSolrClient();
  }

  private SolrClient createStandaloneSolrClient() {
    final String solrUrl = this.solrProperties.getHost();

    return new HttpSolrClient(solrUrl);
  }
}
```

As you can see I am creating embeddedsolrclient or standaloneclient based on some properties set. You can change it to do based on profile(Autowire Environment and check for profile)